# Почему количество элементов с каждым кликом удваиваются?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var addphotolimit = 16;
var i_addphoto = 1;

$('#add_photo').click(function() {
    if (i_addphoto <= addphotolimit) {
        var div_input  = $('.upload_file').last().clone();

        var img = $('<img>');
        img.attr('src', '/public/images/delete.png');
        img.attr('class','remove');
        img.appendTo(div_input);

        $('.upload_file').last().after(div_input);
        i_addphoto++;
    }
        return false;
});
```

Элементов upload_file и img в них

Comment: Клонирование вынесите за пределы обработки клика:

    var addphotolimit = 16,
        i_addphoto = 1,
        div_input  = $('.upload_file').clone();
    
    $('#add_photo').click(function() {
        // ....

Answer (score 1):

Потому что так написано:

```
$('.upload_file').last().after(div_input);
```

Вы каждый раз добавляете элементы после элемента *.upload_file*.
Не совсем каждый раз а первые 16 раз, потом элементы перестанут добавляться.

Если хотите удаляйте их перед добавлением:

```
$('.upload_file').last().remove();
```

Но это может привести к к тому, что селектор $('.upload_file') работать перестанет (если вдруг вы все *.upload_file* удалите).